# Dynamically apply directives to a string of html coming from the server

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string of html which is retrieved from the server with custom directive attributes which Angular should pick up and render. However cannot seem to get the directives to work. Is is possible to load a string of html with some custom directive in it.

This is the sort of thing which I have been doing. I have been passing the html string through the DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml() method to get the markup to render correctly but can't seem to figure out a way to get any directives attached to the various tags to run.

This is a small example of what I want to achieve, markup declared on the server whit custom directives on the client:

```
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from "@angular/core"
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from "@angular/platform-browser"

@Component({
    selector: 'MyComponent',
    templateUrl: '<div [innerHTML]="myContent">',
})

export class MyComponent
{
    dynamicContent: SafeHtml;

    htmlFromTheServer: string = '<p>This is an input: </p><input type="text" custom>';

    constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.dynamicContent = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.htmlFromTheServer);
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[custom]'
})
export class MyDirective
{
    constructor(public element: ElementRef,
                public renderer: Renderer)
    {
        renderer.setElementStyle(element.nativeElement, 'border', '1px solid red');
    }
}
```

If the directive has been applied to the markup it should have a red border around it, but cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: you should create a dynamic component + dynamic module and compile them on your own in order to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

This repo has a good example of a html compiler service https://github.com/patrikx3/ng2-compile-html